# Bind to jQuery event only for particular elements

Tags: colorbox, jquery

I am relatively new to jQuery but the below code seems logical but is not working as I would expect. I am utilizing the [Colorbox jQuery plugin](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).

My intention is to only add a listener for the 'cbox_closed' event on 'a' elements who have an id that contains 'Remove'. Unfortunately, as presently implemented this adds the listener on all raisings of the 'cbox_closed' event.

Am I missing something or is this not a valid means of adding an event listener?

```
$('a[id*="Remove"]').bind('cbox_closed', function() {
    var row = $($.fn.colorbox.element()).parents('tr');
    row.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        row.remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. The problem you're seeing is due to colorbox supporting triggering of the `'cbox_closed'` event *globally* only (i.e. not on specific elements). When in doubt, go to the source:  http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js (search for `cboxPublic.close`). You'll see this: `$.event.trigger(cbox_closed)`.

Comment: @ahsteele: well my comment doesn't solve your problem, only addresses it. Did you try @fudgey's recent answer?

Comment: @CrescentFlash I did and it did the trick was hoping to kill my comment before you saw it. I should have refreshed before hitting the X. ;)

Comment: @ahsteele: should have left your comment up. Now it just looks like I'm having a conversation with myself ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
  if ( $( $.fn.colorbox.element() ).attr('id').match('Remove') ){
   alert('Remove me!');
  }
})
```

The event will always trigger when the ColorBox is closed. You would have to modify the plugin itself to prevent this event from firing in specific cases. So, the above code binds to the event then looks for your specific ID. I hope my explanation helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be

```
$("a[id*='Remove']").bind('cbox_closed', function() {
```

You seem to be missing qoutes around the `Remove` value

Or I misunderstood your problem

Comment: If I am not mistaken I believe he is referring to the instance when the ID's change after the bound event and the ID no longer contains remove.  The bind event would still be bound to those anchors in his code.

Comment: I didn't have the quotes but unfortunately that made no difference. :(